# MFC's dialog-based app title bar highlighting visual artifacts on Windows 10 (i.e. bugs in CDialogEx)

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc, visual-studio-2017, windows-10

I'm not sure why am I getting this visual artifact?

Here's how to repro:

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community. Create a new C++ -> MFC project:

[image]

Then specify "dialog based":

[image]

Then build as "Debug" x86 app and run it.

So I'm running it on Windows 10.

When this dialog-based process has focus, it looks as I would expect it:

[image]

but if I switch keyboard focus to some other app (by clicking on it), this dialog-based process still retains its title bar color:

[image]

I'm not sure if it's just a matter of a visual glitch or if there's a deeper mess-up with the window message handling. How do I correct it? (This wasn't an issue with older MFC projects.)

Comment: I am not even sure how to make Windows switch colors of the title bar, based on whether it has focus.. :/

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: Start -> Settings -> Rationalization -> Colors -> put a check on "Title bars" in "Show accent color on the following surfaces" section.

Comment: Yes, I found that out on my own. When I do that, the title bars doesn't respond to the focus. They just either permanently retain the accent, or permanently do not (depending on the window). I assume that It might change, after I restart my computer, but I don't want to do it, just to test it.

Comment: I can repro. The bug only happens with dialogs derived from `CDialogEx`. After I replaced all occurences of `CDialogEx` with `CDialog`, the problem disappeared.

Comment: @zett42 OK. I haven't looked into MFC lately. What is the difference between `CDialog` and `CDialogEx` for such a drastic solution?

Comment: From a quick look at the MFC source, `CDialog` just inherits `CWnd::OnActivate()` which calls `Default()` (default window procedure), whereas `CDialogEx::OnActivate()` is overridden and sends `WM_FLOATSTATUS` to the active window in certain cases (I'm too tired right now to really understand this code).

Comment: @zett42 It's actually all wrong. When `nState == WA_INACTIVE`, then `pWndOther` points to our same dialog. The next line is basically `if (m_Dlg.GetSafeHwnd() == m_Dlg.GetSafeHwnd()){m_Dlg.m_nFlags |= WF_STAYACTIVE;...}` It's not even affected by `WM_FLOATSTATUS`. `OnNcActivate` does its job right and keeps the dialog look active based on `WA_INACTIVE`. You can remove all that code to fix it, but I am not sure how it affects the program if the dialog has children or siblings etc. with `MFS_SYNCACTIVE` flag.

Comment: I really wonder why MS messed it up once again...

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Yeah, it looks strange that they have this bug in one of the project templates. I'm curious if there's a bug report already submitted into VS2017 portal?

Comment: Reported: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/409317/mfc-dialog-based-application-with-cdialogex.html

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Very good, thank you. So hopefully they'll fix it.

Comment: They got back to me and they say this is not a bug *"Thank you for your feedback! We have determined that this issue is not a bug. It displays a modal dialog after called dlg.DoModal(), the DoModal() function does not return until the user closes the dialog. If the user clicks the "OK/Cancel" button, the DoModal() function returns "IDOK/ IDCANCEL". So this behavior is by-design."* What a joke!

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: yeah, it's pointless to report any bugs. Just use `CDialog` instead like was suggested elsewhere. I personally reported several glaring bugs in VS2017 that lead to crashes and got nowhere. So I doubt that anyone will even consider reviewing MFC source code at this point.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to replicate your problem and found a quick fix for it. 
You need to add the WM_ACTIVATE message handler to your main dialog, comment out the base class OnActivate and modify it like this:

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnActivate(UINT nState, CWnd* pWndOther, BOOL bMinimized)
{
    //CDialogEx::OnActivate(nState, pWndOther, bMinimized);

    // TODO: Add your message handler code here
    this->Default();
}
```

CWnd::Default call is needed to keep the active/inactive visualization of the default button.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Thanks. Let me see what are they messing up there in that handler ...

Comment: @c00000fd the handler sets the default button active or inactive but obviously messes up the frame rendering

Comment: Yeah, it seems like the `CDialogEx::OnActivate` handler calls two methods: `CWnd::Default()` and then `CDialogImpl::OnActivate()`. The latter one seems to be causing this issue, or maybe it sending out the `WM_FLOATSTATUS` message does. (I'm not really sure what it's for, though.) The solution seems to be commenting out `CDialogEx::OnActivate` like you suggested, but then adding `this->Default();` instead.

Comment: @c00000fd Thanks for the clarification, the answer is updated.

Comment: If anyone has a better solution please post it. Otherwise I'll mark this one as the answer.

Comment: Hmm. There's still some kinda screw-up there. I'm not sure if it's related to this fix or not. Ex: If you create a button and then in its handler try to do: `CFileDialog d(TRUE, NULL, NULL, OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_EXPLORER, NULL, this);d.DoModal();` to open a file picker dialog. When file picker opens up, close it and see if the title bar of the parent MFC dialog window goes back to being active. In my case it remains inactive until I click onto the Windows taskbar and then back onto that MFC app.

Comment: @c00000fd It seems that CFileDialog also has this issue. It might be worth investigating its code and trying to override WM_ACTIVATE. However, a much simpler workaround is to add FlashWindow(TRUE); after DoModal. BTW, this problem doesn't occur with About box (activated via the system menu) which is also a CDialogEx based dialog.

Comment: No, `CFileDialog` isn't buggy. `CDialogEx` is. I had to post my own answer to this issue. Thanks for trying to help though.

Answer (score 2):

OK, as much as I appreciate @VuVirt's solution, it doesn't completely remove all the bugs that are shipped in the default Dialog-based solution in VS2017. It solves the title bar focus issue, but while continuing to develop my project I encountered another bug. So I'm copy-and-pasting it from my comment to his answer:

> There's still some kinda screw-up there. I'm not sure if it's related to this fix or not. Ex: If you create a button and then in its handler try to do: CFileDialog d(TRUE, NULL, NULL, OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_EXPLORER, NULL, this); d.DoModal(); to open a file picker dialog. When file picker opens up, close it and see if the title bar of the parent MFC dialog window goes back to being active. In my case it remains inactive until I click onto the Windows taskbar and then back onto that MFC app.

After banging my head against the wall trying to see what is going on there, I decided to try an earlier solution proposed by @zett42 in the comments to my original question (i.e. to replace CDialogEx with CDialog) and it worked! All the bugs are gone!

So here's my verdict: `CDialogEx` is buggy af.

**The resolution is quite simple:** When you create a new dialog-based project use project-wide find-and-replace (in the Edit menu) and replace all occurrences of `CDialogEx` with `CDialog`. And that is it. (I tried to use VS2017's refactoring tool for that but it messed it up and didn't replace it all. So simple search-and-replace does the job.)

And if you think that you'll be missing some functionality without `CDialogEx`, then you won't. All it does (besides introducing bugs) is that it adds background images and colors to the dialog.

So until MS fixes those glaring bugs in their templates I'm sticking with this approach.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in `CDialogImpl::OnActivate` and `CDialogImpl::OnNcActivate`:

> ```
> void CDialogImpl::OnNcActivate(BOOL& bActive)
> {
>   if (m_Dlg.m_nFlags & WF_STAYACTIVE)
>       bActive = TRUE;
>   if (!m_Dlg.IsWindowEnabled())
>       bActive = FALSE;
> }
>
> void CDialogImpl::OnActivate(UINT nState, CWnd* pWndOther)
> {
>   m_Dlg.m_nFlags &= ~WF_STAYACTIVE;
>   CWnd* pWndActive = (nState == WA_INACTIVE) ? pWndOther : &m_Dlg;
>   if (pWndActive != NULL)
>   {
>       BOOL bStayActive = (pWndActive->GetSafeHwnd() == m_Dlg.GetSafeHwnd()
>             || pWndActive->SendMessage(WM_FLOATSTATUS, FS_SYNCACTIVE));
>       if (bStayActive)
>           m_Dlg.m_nFlags |= WF_STAYACTIVE;
>   }
>   else
>   {
>       m_Dlg.SendMessage(WM_NCPAINT, 1);
>   }
> }
> ```

This is meant to give `CDialogEx` the ability to stay active, for example, when `CMFCPopupMenu` is shown.

But `m_Dlg.SendMessage(WM_NCPAINT, 1)` is a suspicious call. The usage doesn't match the documentation for [`WM_NCPAINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/wm-ncpaint):

> Parameters
>
> `wParam`
>      A handle to the update region of the window. The update region is clipped to the window frame.
>
> `lParam`
>
> This parameter is not used.

Additionally, `OnNcActivate` has an override based on `IsWindowEnabled()`. This seems to be a patch to fix the earlier problem in `OnActivate`. But it causes problems elsewhere, for example when using `CFileDialog` in `CDialogEx`

Suggested solution:

Modify `CDialogEx::OnActivate` so that it runs the default procedure. Or, change it such that it will force repaint.

```
BOOL CDialogEx::OnNcActivate(BOOL active)
{
    if(m_nFlags & WF_STAYACTIVE)
        active = TRUE;
    return(BOOL)DefWindowProc(WM_NCACTIVATE, active, 0L);
}

void CDialogEx::OnActivate(UINT nState, CWnd* pWndOther, BOOL bMinimized)
{
    Default();
}
```

or

```
void CDialogEx::OnActivate(UINT nState, CWnd* pWndOther, BOOL bMinimized)
{
    Default();

    //save the previous flag
    UINT previous_flag = m_nFlags;
    m_nFlags &= ~WF_STAYACTIVE;

    // Determine if this window should be active or not:
    CWnd* pWndActive = (nState == WA_INACTIVE) ? pWndOther : this;
    if(pWndActive != NULL)
    {
        BOOL bStayActive = pWndActive->GetSafeHwnd() == GetSafeHwnd() ||
            pWndActive->SendMessage(WM_FLOATSTATUS, FS_SYNCACTIVE);
        if(bStayActive)
            m_nFlags |= WF_STAYACTIVE;
    }

    if(previous_flag != m_nFlags && previous_flag & WF_STAYACTIVE)
    {
        //if the flag is changed, 
        //and if WF_STAYACTIVE was previously set, 
        //then OnNcActivate had handled it wrongly, do it again
        SendMessage(WM_NCACTIVATE, FALSE); //<- less wrong!
    }
}
```

This should work with `CMFCPopupMenu` for example. The MFC menu will open without deactivating the dialog.

I am not sure what `SendMessage(WM_FLOATSTATUS, FS_SYNCACTIVE)` is for, I haven't been able to test it... If it's necessary, it seems the code could be added on `OnNcActivate`, and then `OnActivate` is left alone.

Comment: Thanks for your analysis. Unfortunately there's too many bugs in that `CDialogEx` to justify using it. [Like I said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53791255/843732), simply replacing it with `CDialog` seems to do the trick. What I'm curious about, did they totally abandon any MFC/C++ in favor of .NET, WPF and other stuff that Visual Studio is packed with? It's been about 2 years since VS2017 was out and we're still seeing these glaring bugs in one of the main MFC classes. Their wizard creates any MFC dialog derived from that `CDialogEx` by default.

Comment: No, it works fine with `CFileDialog`. It needs additional override for `OnNcActivate`. The purpose of this post was to describe the problem which has to be fixed by Microsoft.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Are you going to report it to them then? If so can you post a link so that we don't do it multiple times.

Comment: And no, it doesn't work fine with CFileDialog. It's a somewhat different issue (again see my explanation in a separate answer) but it is still a bug in CDialogEx.

Comment: Did you add override for `OnNcActivate`? See the second suggestion I posted, it's shorter. Anyway, `CDialog` will work fine unless you are adding stuff like `CMFCPopupMenu`

Comment: No, I didn't try any of your suggestions. That's why I can't confirm or deny it. (I'll let others do it.) I chose an option of replacing it with CDialog. I don't need any of that other fluff CDialogEx brings. I wasted too much time already trying to fix their bugs.